# Unreachable Peer and Address out of range when reading Siemens S7-1500 PLC using Python

Tags: python, runtime-error, plc, snap7

When I'm reading PLC (Siemens S7-1500) data using Profinet protocol in Python, it's getting 'Unreachable peer' and [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SdCnx.png)'Address out of range' errors. So, I can't read the values. Why is this?

Here I'm adding a part of the Python code. I'm not revealing my IP address but it is accessible.

```
import snap7
from snap7.exceptions import Snap7Exception

rack = 0
slot = 1

def profinet(plc_ip_address, rack, slot, r_db_number, Plant, Packet):
    while True:
        try:
            # Connect to the PLC
            plc = snap7.client.Client()
            plc.connect(plc_ip_address, rack, slot, 102)
```

I did the same process for Siemens S7-300 PLC and read the values. I just changed the IP, Rack=0, Slot=1 in the program. But its continuously giving these errors.

Answer (score 1):

Snap7 is just simple S7-protocol connection via TCP/IP (**it is not Profinet tool**).
Those two are important:

1. Please check if [PUT/GET](https://iautomatyka.pl/wp-content/uploads/2019/03/12.png) communication is enabled.
2. If you polling DB, make sure that it doesn't have optimized access.